# How to fix rain water missing gutter on the 2nd floor?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, gutters

[image]When it rains, rain water not going into the 2nd floor gutter but coming down straight on the ground. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: At this level of detail? "Fix the gutter." Please [edit] your question to include pictures of the problem area, and a more complete problem description. If no water is going into the second floor gutter, and it's all going straight to the ground, the gutter is in the wrong place. That's what you described. If your actual problem is differerent (like one area overflows) describe the actual problem in some detail. We can't see your roof (until you post a picture)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The roof is there to shield the home.  Shedding rain is one of it's jobs.  Is there a problem having the rain fall to the ground?

Comment: @RMDman yes, erosion potential, and water ending up too close to the home.

Comment: @huesmann, remember if you damage a roof deck from rain water backing up it is far more expensive to repair than some erosion that can also have a cure if one looks at it properly.

Comment: @RMDman never said otherwise.  You asked if there is a problem, and I said what one is.

Comment: @huesmann, So you are also "Guest"?  Or do you always know what the exact issue is with peoples homes?

Answer (score 3):

The roof looks like it has a valley, the part where 2 roofs running perpendicular to each other meet, and the rain coming off the 2 roofs converge there. The gutter needs to be either added onto, to go around the corner, or redone to include the 90 degree turn. A diverter alone will not work, since it will cause a trap at the roof edge until the water builds up enough to get to the gutter. After the gutter is completed, then a diverter can be added to insure all the water gets to the added gutter.

I just remembered, [a scupper or collector](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Flovettgutters.com%2Frain-collector-boxes-and-leader-heads&psig=AOvVaw3eXSoULliqtwoxHNJqh2vY&ust=1693191849912000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBIQ3YkBahcKEwjgm_yn7fuAAxUAAAAAHQAAAAAQKg) with its own dedicated downspout would be simpler still, no need to rework the gutter.

Comment: You don't think a piece of flashing would be enough to drive the water down to the gutter?

Comment: @matt. , the overhang where the gutter is mounted is away from the valley by about 8", most of the water converges at that one spot. Picture a folded piece of paper or cardboard cut to mimic the situation, with the roof sloped, the water will need to build up a bit before it goes into the gutter.  If it were done, the flashing would need to go up under the shingles far enough to keep the raised water level contained until it goes in the gutter. If the flashing is no far enough up, even though it may only be an inch or two of water, it would get to the roof sheathing and start damage in time.

Comment: Copy, I was just thinking a piece of step flashing would help redirect the runoff.  Upvoted.

Comment: FWIW, adding flashing into the valley, but not across it all the way to the gutter may reduce a lot of it. Adding the elbow will get it all.

Comment: Agreed. An elbow at the gutter termination would be the best solution.

Comment: I added a link to a website that has the mentioned collector boxes, since the picture did not want to upload.